# Bean validation - Combining validation groups and group sequence

Tags: java, spring, validation, hibernate-validator

I have simple entity with some validations. I want some of them to run in certain order, and other to run only in particural case. So far I end with something like this, but dont know how to use the groups properly.

Entity class

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @NotBlank                       //This should go FIRST
    @Email(regexp = "xxxxx")        //This should go SECOND
    @UniqueEmail                    //This should go THIRD but only on create
    private String email;
    
    @NotBlank                       //This should go FIRST
    @Length(min = 8)                //This should go FIRST
    private String password;
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public void addUser(@Validated(OnCreate.class) User user){...}
    public void updateUser(User user){...}
}
```

Validation groups

```
public class UserValidationGroups {
    @GroupSequence({Default.class, EmailFormatValid.class, UniqueEmail.class})
    public interface UserValidationGroupSeqence{}
    public interface UniqueEmail{}
    public interface EmailFormatValid{}
    
}
```

How can I make these validation to work the way as commented?

Comment: the `@NotBlank` and `@Email`(it is validate then not blank) validation are  independent,  so there is no need to controll the validation order

Answer (score 0):

Note that having validation group sequences means that as soon as one of the groups defined in the sequence generates at least one constraint violation, no further groups will be processed. With that said, one way to approach this could be:

Add groups to your constraints:

```
class User {
    @NotBlank                                               // leave in the default group
    @Email(regexp = ".*@email.com", groups = Second.class)  // need to have a group to put it in the "second round" of validation
    @UniqueEmail(groups = Third.class)                      // need to have a group to put it in the "third round" of validation
    private String email;

    @NotBlank                       // leave in the default group
    @Length(min = 8)                // leave in the default group
    private String password;

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and then define your sequences as:

```
@GroupSequence({Default.class, Second.class, Third.class})
interface UserCreateValidationGroupSequence {}

@GroupSequence({Default.class, Second.class})
interface UserUpdateValidationGroupSequence {}
```

and then you'd pass either create or update sequence to the validator, in your case, it could be:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public void addUser(@Validated(UserCreateValidationGroupSequence.class) User user){...}
    public void updateUser(@Validated(UserUpdateValidationGroupSequence.class) User user){...}
}
```

Now, if you'd like to keep the `updateUser()` service call without passing the specific group(sequence) and only mark it with `@Valid/@Validated` you can consider looking at default group sequence redefinition. In such case, you'd add the default (update) sequence definition to your class:

```
@GroupSequence({User.class, Second.class})
class User {
    @NotBlank                                               // leave in the default group
    @Email(regexp = ".*@email.com", groups = Second.class)  // need to have a group to put it in the "second round" of validation
    @UniqueEmail(groups = Third.class)                      // need to have a group to put it in the "third round" of validation
    private String email;

    @NotBlank                       // leave in the default group
    @Length(min = 8)                // leave in the default group
    private String password;

}
```

have the create sequence:

```
@GroupSequence({Default.class, Second.class, Third.class})
interface UserCreateValidationGroupSequence {}
```

and finally, in service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    public void addUser(@Validated(UserCreateValidationGroupSequence.class) User user){...}
    public void updateUser(@Valid User user){...}
}
```